# Which AWS gems are really necessary for Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Paperclip suggests using the aws-sdk gem for integrating with AWS S3, but the gem has a ridiculous amount of dependencies! **Is there a better way to configure AWS gems for Paperclip?**

These are all the gems installed when you use aws-sdk:

```
aws-partitions (1.44.0)
aws-sdk (3.0.1)
aws-sdk-acm (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-alexaforbusiness (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-apigateway (1.7.0)
aws-sdk-applicationautoscaling (1.6.0)
aws-sdk-applicationdiscoveryservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-appstream (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-appsync (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-athena (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-autoscaling (1.4.0)
aws-sdk-batch (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-budgets (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-cloud9 (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-clouddirectory (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudformation (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-cloudfront (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cloudhsm (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-cloudhsmv2 (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cloudsearch (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudsearchdomain (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudtrail (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudwatch (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-cloudwatchevents (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cloudwatchlogs (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-codebuild (1.4.0)
aws-sdk-codecommit (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-codedeploy (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-codepipeline (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-codestar (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cognitoidentity (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cognitosync (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-comprehend (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-configservice (1.4.0)
aws-sdk-core (3.11.0)
aws-sdk-costandusagereportservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-costexplorer (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-databasemigrationservice (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-datapipeline (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-dax (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-devicefarm (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-directconnect (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-directoryservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-dynamodb (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-dynamodbstreams (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-ec2 (1.21.0)
aws-sdk-ecr (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-ecs (1.5.0)
aws-sdk-efs (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-elasticache (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-elasticbeanstalk (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-elasticloadbalancing (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2 (1.6.0)
aws-sdk-elasticsearchservice (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-elastictranscoder (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-emr (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-firehose (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-gamelift (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-glacier (1.5.0)
aws-sdk-glue (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-greengrass (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-guardduty (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-health (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-iam (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-importexport (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-inspector (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-iot (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-iotdataplane (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-iotjobsdataplane (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-kinesis (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-kinesisanalytics (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-kinesisvideo (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-kinesisvideoarchivedmedia (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-kinesisvideomedia (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-kms (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-lambda (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-lambdapreview (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-lex (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-lexmodelbuildingservice (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-lightsail (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-machinelearning (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-marketplaceentitlementservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-marketplacemetering (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mediaconvert (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-medialive (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mediapackage (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mediastore (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mediastoredata (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-migrationhub (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mobile (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mq (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mturk (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-opsworks (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-opsworkscm (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-organizations (1.7.0)
aws-sdk-pinpoint (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-polly (1.4.0)
aws-sdk-pricing (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-rds (1.8.0)
aws-sdk-redshift (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-rekognition (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-resourcegroups (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-resourcegroupstaggingapi (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-resources (3.8.0)
aws-sdk-route53 (1.5.0)
aws-sdk-route53domains (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-s3 (1.8.0)
aws-sdk-sagemaker (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-sagemakerruntime (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-serverlessapplicationrepository (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-servicecatalog (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-ses (1.4.0)
aws-sdk-shield (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-simpledb (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-sms (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-snowball (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-sns (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-sqs (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-ssm (1.5.0)
aws-sdk-states (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-storagegateway (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-support (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-swf (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-translate (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-waf (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-wafregional (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-workdocs (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-workspaces (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-xray (1.1.0)
aws-sigv2 (1.0.1)
aws-sigv4 (1.0.2)
```